# where are my UIBarButtonItem & UIToolbar on UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone app, on the top of screen there is an UIToolbar, there are 2 UIBarButtonItem on the UIToolbar.

One is 'Cancel' another is 'Confirm'.
But if I migrate the project to ipad and present the view/ViewController using UIPopoverController, these two UIBarButtonItem & UIToolbar disappear.

I know if I touch anywhere outside the UIPopoverController, it will disappear, but I prefer to keep the UIBarButtonItems to ask for confirmation of some option.

Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Comment: Be sure to position the toolbar in the frame of the presented popoverController view (set with: yourView.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(...))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popoverController does not dissapear by itself when you click outsite. The code that makes it dissapear is:

```
if([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }
```

Comment: if you want to implement your Cancel button, just set it's selector to close the popover: [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the UIToolbar to the viewcontroller's view before presenting it in the popover.